# Powershell Operators -like

Tags: powershell

Are there any other operators I can use to filter out my Client Version column? I have tried using the following code. What I am doing is filtering out my certain Operating Systems and then I am looking to Filter my Client Version column to Version 12.

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\SEPM Exports\Computer Status Export 7_13_2017.csv' 
$csv | Select "Version", "Operating System","Client Version","Policy Version","Computer Name","Computer Domain Name","Current login domain", "Current User" |
Where{"Windows 7 Enterprise Edition","Windows 10 Enterprise Edition","Windows 7 Professional Edition" -contains $_.'Operating System' -or      $_."Client Version" -like "12.1.*"} |
Export-Csv "C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\SEPM Exports\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)-Computer Status Export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Whenever I run the whole script, it gives me some version 14's as well?

Comment: Then maybe you want `-and` instead. Note also that recent versions of PowerShell have `-in`, so you don't have to use the more awkward `-contains`.

Comment: `$_."Client Version" -match '^(12|14)\.'`

Answer (score 0):

If I read your problem correctly then this is happening as you are using the -or operator instead of the -and which is your main issue.

Can you try the following (contains a tweak for matching multiple strings and a little clean-up for readability purposes):

```
#setup a list of keyword searches
$keywords= @('Windows 7 Enterprise Edition', 'Windows 10 Enterprise Edition', 'Windows 7 Professional Edition')   
#setup regex to match multi when called 
$concatOrRegex = [string]::Join('|', $keywords)
#columns you want
$columns = "Version", "Operating System","Client Version","Policy Version","Computer Name","Computer Domain Name","Current login domain", "Current User"
#output file
$outputFile = "C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\SEPM Exports\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)-Computer Status Export.csv"
#imput file
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\SEPM Exports\Computer Status Export 7_13_2017.csv' 

#filter and export
$csv | Select $columns | Where{ $_.'Operating System' -match $concatOrRegex -and $_."Client Version" -like "12.1.*"} | Export-Csv $outputFile  -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Just addressing this line to solve your requested issue:

```
Where{"Windows 7 Enterprise Edition","Windows 10 Enterprise Edition","Windows 7 Professional Edition" -contains $_.'Operating System' -or      $_."Client Version" -like "12.1.*"} |
```

As your logic is written you are getting any object whose OS matches the list you provided regardless of the 'Client Version'. Then you are getting any object whose 'Client Version' is "12.1.*". The -Or clause is then telling PowerShell essentially to return both of those lists combined.

As Jeroen Mostert pointed out, you need to use -and instead of -or. Alternatively, you could use 2 where clauses to have easier to understand code. Here the first where clause produces a list filtered by OS and the second where clause then filters that list on the Client Version:

```
*Your_CSV_output* | Where {"Windows 7 Enterprise Edition","Windows 10 Enterprise Edition","Windows 7 Professional Edition" -contains $_.'Operating System' } | Where { $_."Client Version" -like "12.1.*"}
```